# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: voice is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I realize that posts about this kind of topic exists, but I'm really new to JS and wouldn't really be able to understand if it's not about what I'm doing specifically. I'm trying to make a music bot for discord following along and trying to learn from a tutorial, and it didn't recognize that I was in a voice channel, so it wouldn't play anything. Then this error started showing up after a little looking around to see what I did wrong. It also gives me this error message: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.` Which I'm not really sure how to fix. It says "This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()." But again, as I'm new to this I really don't understand what that means.

Ignore the ill-mannered Swedish by the way, but here is the entire thing:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {
    prefix,
    token,
} = require('./config.json');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const queue = new Map();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});
client.once('reconnecting', () => {
    console.log('Reconnecting!');
});
client.once('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('¨Disconnect!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
        execute(message, serverQueue);
        return;
    }   else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
        skip(message, serverQueue);
    }   else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {
        stop(message, serverQueue);
        return;
    }
});

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
    const args = message.content.split(" ");

    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.Channel;
    if (!voice.channel)
        return message.channel.send(
            "Hur fan ska jag kunna spela musik om du inte är i en kanal? Jävla mongo."
        );
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
        return message.channel.send(
            "Ok, så du vill att jag spelar upp musik, men ger mig inte tillåtelse att spela upp musik? Fixa dina perms dumfan."
        );
    }

    let song;
    if (ytdl.validateURL(args[1])) {
        const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
        song = {
            title: songInfo.title,
            url: songInfo.video_url
        };
    } else {
        const {videos} = await yts(args.slice(1).join(" "));
        if (!videos.length) return message.channel.send("No songs were found!");
        song = {
            title: videos[0].title,
            url: videos[0].url
        };
    }


    if (!serverQueue) {
        const queueContruct = {
            textChannel: message.channel,
            voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
            connection: null,
            songs: [],
            volume: 5,
            playing: true,
        };

    queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

    queueContruct.songs.push(song);

    try {
        var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        queueContruct.connection = connection;
        play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
    }   catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        queue.delete(message.guild.id);
        return message.channel.send(err);
    }
}else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song);
    return message.channel.send(`${song.title}? Ok, lägger till den i kön.`);
    }
}

function skip(message, serverQueue) {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel)
      return message.channel.send(
        "Du måste var i en röstkanal för att stoppa musik din dumma jävel."
      );
    if (!serverQueue)
      return message.channel.send("Det finns ingen låt att skippa dtt sär.");
    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop(message, serverQueue) {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel)
      return message.channel.send(
        "Du måste var i en röstkanal för att stoppa musik din dumma jävel."
      );
    
    if (!serverQueue)
      return message.channel.send("Det finns ingen låt att stoppa dtt sär.");
      
    serverQueue.songs = [];
    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
    if (!song) {
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
        .play(ytdl(song.url))
        .on("finish", () => {
            serverQueue.songs-shift();
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
        .on("error", error => console.error(error));
    dispatcher.setVolume.Logarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
    serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Nu spelar jag: **${song.title}** din hora`);
}

client.login(token);
```

Don't know if I did this post right...
And sorry about the formatting.
Thanks in advance though!

Comment: Typo. `if (!voice.channel)` should be `if (!voiceChannel)`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Thank you! That fixed that error message, however it still doesn't recognize that I'm in a voice chat unfortunately.